# Flatten array of array with sum returning only one level

Tags: javascript

I have a lodash flatten function, but I need to add the sum of all nested arrays to the result.

For example, for this AoA:

```
[[[1,2,3],[1,5]], [[1,1,2]]]
```

The result should be:

```
[16,12,6,1,2,3,6,1,5,4,1,1,2]
```

What is an efficient way to do that?

This is what I did so far, but it is returning only one level of sum:

```
function buildDataFromAOA(aoa) {
    if (!aoa[0].length) 
        return [aoa.reduce((sum, item) => sum += item, 0)].concat(aoa);

    let data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < aoa.length; i++) {
        data = data.concat(buildDataFromAOA(aoa[i]))
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: What is the logic to achieve this output? Also share your attempt

Comment: @gurvinder372 He's inserting the sum from each array with multiple members in front of the respective array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an array as accumulator and with taking zero at index zero for the sum of the following items.

Basically it adds the actual value to the sum value of index zero and pushes the actual value to the end of the accumulator.

If an array is found, the array is checked for the length of one and if the first/only item of the array is an array, then the item variable is set to the child array and so on.

Then the array is reduced with the same callback and an array with first element is for summing and the rest is for the items of the array.

With the returned array, the first item is added to the actual accumulator first item and the the accumulator is concatinated with to whole array and returned.

```js
var array = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 5]], [[1, 1, 2]]],
    result = array.reduce(function fn(r, a) {
        var t;
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
            while (a.length === 1 && Array.isArray(a[0])) { a = a[0]; }
            t = a.reduce(fn, [0]);
            r[0] += t[0];
            return r.concat(t);
        }
        r[0] += a;
        r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, [0]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Nearly the same in a single function

```js
function fn(array) {
    var result = [0];

    while (array.length === 1 && Array.isArray(array[0])) {
        array = array[0];
    }
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var t;
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
            t = fn(a);
            result[0] += t[0];
            Array.prototype.push.apply(result, t);
            return;
        }
        result[0] += a;
        result.push(a);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(fn([[[1, 2, 3], [1, 5]], [[1, 1, 2]]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```